# How to Run a Program (which is compiled on Local Machine) on a Remote Machine through ssh?

Tags: ssh, scp

I want to run a program which its files is located and compiled in local machine on a remote machine through `ssh`. I used to `scp` (copy through ssh) its compiled files to remote machine and then run it. Is it possible to escape `scp` and run it from local machine?

Comment: You need to provide some more informations like if both architectures are equal and if you have to enter password or if you use keys.

Comment: @rekire:Architectures may be not equal, and about password I `sshpass -p "paasword"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rekire's suggestion is reasonable.

alternatively, you could mount (part of) the developments machine file system on the target machine with sshfs and execute the remote binary as if it were stored locally on the target.

for more information on sshfs see e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS

Comment: +1 I like the idea. This would make the copying part unnecessary. But does it allow to execute files? I'm not sure about this point.

Comment: it does allow to execute files. it makes the explicit triggering of the copying unnecessary, but the data-moves-over-the-wire-part is still there, and depending on the caches within sshfs it is worse than with the explicit copy, because data might be transmitted repeatedly, especially after a remount. personally i'd go with a rsync-based approach.

Comment: @mnagel:I tried it myself but I just want to be sure.If I use sshfs to mount a directory with readonly files, are those files mounted on target machine as readonly? Even readonly to "root" of target machine?And target machine's root can not change permissions.yes?

Comment: lets call the other machine source. you specify a user on source for the ssh connection when mounting with sshfs on target. from source's point of view the files are modified by that user, no matter what user you do use on target. so that user's permissions are applied and cannot be elevated above what would be possible on source itself.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that both computers have the same architecture or that you cross compiled them to fit on the target.

I would use this two commands:

```
scp yourapp target:/path/to/store/yourapp
ssh target /path/to/store/yourapp
```

That requires that you have a running ssh setup which auths you on the target system.

There are several ways to setup this you could try this page http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html

Comment: I said that I used to do what you said, but I want to know if it is possible to run the program without needing to copy it to remote machine.

Comment: No that is not possible, I mean th know some grid computing tools that can achieve that too, but they will do that transparency the same way.